# Returning 2 Dimensional array in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, asmx

I'm using .asmx web service that will return 2 dimensional array where I want to return like `row1={'id1','name1'}, row2={'id2','name2'}` but I'm not being able to do so.

**Code Section**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public Array getAlbumsAndPhotos()
{
    DataTable resultText = new DataTable();
    resultText = AdminUserDataAccess.getAlbumsAndPhotosforAsmx();
    string[,] ResultResponse = new string[resultText.Rows.Count , resultText.Columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < resultText.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < resultText.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            ResultResponse[i, j] = resultText.Rows[i][j].ToString();

        }
    }
    return ResultResponse;
}
```

This gives me output as:

```
    [0,0]:"id1"
    [0,1]:"name1"
    [1,0]:"id2"
    [1,1]:"name2"
```

I want two rows to be returned not four with single 0th index(with id1 and name1) and 1st index(with id2 and name2). Some type of nested array output is expected. But I'm not being able to do so. Any help is appreciated. :)

**Edit: Solution**

```
    [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string[]> getAlbumsAndPhotos()
{
    DataTable resultText = new DataTable();
    resultText = AdminUserDataAccess.getAlbumsAndPhotosforAsmx();
    string[] rowsValues = new string[resultText.Rows.Count];
    var list = new List<string[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < resultText.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string col1 = resultText.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        string col2 = resultText.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        list.Add(new[] { col1, col2});
    }
    return list;
```

I can use List or Array list to implement this. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ accssharma: I find it really surprising if you're actually getting the response you've quoted, since that's invalid JSON. I wouldn't expect ASP.Net to produce invalid JSON regardless of what you give it. I'd expect it to fail, or to produce valid JSON.

Comment: Use single dimension array and put comma separated value in it

Comment: @accssharma: *"Ok, I might go wrong with what I've quoted..."* Then correct it. Don't give incorrect information in  your question. Use the Net tab in your browser's debugger to quote *exactly* what gets sendt back.

Comment: I'm saying exactly what I'm getting with above code. I'm not giving incorrect information. I just want to return two dimensional array via above code. That's it.